# How to represent composite Flagged Enum values in XML config file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, enums, flags

If I have a flagged enum lets say for argument

```
[Flags]
public enum Shipping { Null=0x00, FedX=0x01, UPS=0x02, AirBrn=0x04, USPS=0x08, Any=0xFF}
```

and I want to store this value in an Xml config file, such as

```
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="shipper")]
  public Shipping ShippingOption { get; set; }
```

I know that I have to separate combined values with a space, for example, If I want the config file to represent ShippingOption as either FedX or UPS, then the Xml would look like this:

```
  <ElementName shipper="FedX UPS" />
```

or if I want it to represent FedX or UPS or USPS then

```
  <ElementName shipper="FedX UPS USPS" />
```

But what do I put in the attribute if I want it to be anything but UPS? 
(Assuming the enum does not have a predefined value for this (like `Shipping.Any`) 
This would be the equivalent of c# value

```
       var ship = Shipping.Any & ^Shipping.UPS;
```

I know I could just leave out the one I don't want, like this:

```
 <ElementName shipper="FedX USPS AirBrn " />
```

But if there are many many members in the Enum that gets tedious, (and would require maintenance anytime the complete list expanded).  Is there a short hand way to represent Negation of a flagged Enum ?

Comment: FYI, it's [FedEx](http://www.fedex.com/us/)

Comment: oh, thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: I would use the composite `int` value of the flag and write that out as the attribute value.

Comment: you mean like `<ElementName shipper="0xc7" /> ` ? Will that work ? I guess I will try it. although it is way less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly crude solution that should work. First, write a method to parse your custom enum syntax—in my implementation, `~X` means 'and not `X`':

```
private T ParseEnum<T>(string str) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    var result = 0;
    foreach (var name in str.Split())
    {
        if (name.StartsWith("~"))
        {
            result &= ~(int)(Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name.Substring(1), true));
        }
        else
        {
            result |= (int)(Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name, true));
        }
    }

    return (T)(object)result;
}
```

And here's a *very* simple format function that's compatible with the original XML serialization:

```
private string FormatEnum<T>(T s) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return s.ToString().Replace(",", "");
}
```

Now just set up a proxy property wherever you need to use this and make sure you mark the original with `XmlIgnore`:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Shipping ShippingOption { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shipper")]
public string ShippingOptionString
{
    get { return FormatEnum<Shipping>ShippingOption); }
    set { ShippingOption = ParseEnum<Shipping>(value); }
}
```

Now it will be able to correctly parse XML like this:

```
<ElementName shipper="Any ~UPS" />
```

Other solutions exist for different serialization libraries, but the pattern would basically be the same. Deserialize a the XML attribute as string, then parse it using your custom parser to get the enum result you want.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need.  I feel kinda silly I didn't think of it myself, I use this technique to address other Xml serialization issues already, just didn't think of it! But this is first time I've heard the term `proxy property`.